Generating Certificates for Completed Courses in Certificate Course Management System (CCMS) built on PERN Stack
This question is particularly important as I'm preparing for a project showcase at my university on April 16th.
I'm building a Certificate Course Management System (CCMS) using the PERN (PostgreSQL, Express, React, Node.js) stack.
Problem:
When a student completes a course, I need to generate a certificate for them. The certificate should include some information about the student (e.g., name, email) and details about the completed course (e.g., course name, instructor name, completion date).
What I've Tried:
I've explored various approaches to generating certificates, including researching libraries or frameworks specific to the PERN stack. However, I'm unsure which approach would be the most suitable for my project. I expected to find clear guidance or examples on how to implement certificate generation within the PERN stack, considering its popularity among web developers. However, I haven't found comprehensive resources that address my specific requirements.
Request:
I'm seeking guidance on the best approach to implement this feature in the context of the PERN stack. Are there any libraries or frameworks specific to PERN that can simplify the process? Additionally, as a novice developer, I want to ensure that I follow best practices and conventions while implementing this feature.
GitHub Repository:
I have the project hosted on GitHub in the master branch: CCMS

Additional Information:
As a novice developer, I may not have maintained best practices or conventions throughout the project. Any advice on improving code quality and adherence to conventions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance!


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What I would do is to save the progress of the course in the database and then have a button on the course which allows you to generate a PDF.
When a course is done by the user, you should generate a unique id associated with the user and the course, and make it available for everyone to see (www.ccms.com/certificates/{guid}), like that, it's a proof that the user didn't photoshop or generated the certificate himself.
You can use PDFKit or Puppeteer to generate the PDF, or you can create a specific page to show the certificate in HTML and let the user print it.
